# Ocaml use of a recursive function

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have to write a recursive function that calculates the sum of all the positive integers smaller than n.

My function works at top level but I cannot manage to use it in a script:

```ml
let rec sum x = 
    if x = 0 then 0 else x + sum (x - 1)

let () = 
    Printf.printf "%d\n" sum 4
```

I get the following error at compilation:

```
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b is not compatible with type unit
```

for the last line.

Comment: What is "a script"? OCaml is a compiled language. It doesn't have any script-like functionality as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Anyway, the problem seems to be that `Printf.printf "%d\n" sum 4` calls `printf` with three arguments, the last two being `sum` and `4`. To call `sum` with `4` and then pass the result of that to `printf` you have to parenthesize it.

Comment: @glennsl it does, `ocaml myscript.ml` behaves as a bytecode compilation followed by an execution. oasis used it extensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some parentheses. You want this:

```
let () = 
    Printf.printf "%d\n" (sum 4)
```

This would not have worked in toplevel either.

Without the parentheses, you are asking to pass `sum` (your function itself) as a parameter to `printf`.